# Помогите с решением задачи

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, ряды

Собственно условие задачи:

"Создать программу, которая будет считать функцию sin(x) **с точностью ε**, используя следующую форму разложения в ряд. Результат сравнить со значением полученым стандартной функцией sin(x)
[image: форма разложения]

Задачу нужно решить с помощью цикла с неизвестным числом повторений. Не могу понять что за "точность ε" и что использовать в качестве условия в случае с while

**upd**

Что-то да написал, проблема только с факториалом, а именно при компиляции пишет "идентификатор не найден"

```
    int main()
{
    int x;    // Градус 
    cin >> x;
    double e; // Точность
    cin >> e;
    double sinx = sin(x); // значение обычной функции sin(x)
    int calcx = x; // начальное значение функции разложенной в ряд
    int n = 0; // счётчик
    while (sinx - calcx > e)
    {
        n++;
        calcx += pow(-1,n)*(pow(x, 3) / faktorial(2 * n + 1));
    }

    system("pause");
}

int faktorial(int numb)
{
    int result = 1; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= numb; i++) 
        result *= i; 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то, спрашивая, надо показать своим наработки, а не просить сделать все от и до...

Comment: Понял, просто впервые пользуюсь этим ресурсом, сильно не бейте)

Comment: Смотрите дополненное решение. И совет: когда вот так дополнили - напишите комментарий для того, кому вы ответили. Потому что сюда второй раз я попал, в общем-то, случайно. А так я бы увидел уведомление о комментарии, и посмотрел бы куда раньше...

Answer (score 2):

В знакопеременном с монотонно убывающими членами ряде погрешность суммы ряда не превышает последнего отброшенного члена. Это о точности.

Далее - рассмотрите отношение соседних членов ряда. Далее - цикл с суммированием: из последнего суммированного члена вычисляем новый, прибавляем к сумме, и проверяем, не меньше ли он заданной точности.

Пишите. Когда напишете хоть что-то, кроме задания, поговорим о вашем решении...

P.S. Отлично, раз написали - теперь можно и поправить. Каждый член не надо искать с нуля - я же писал: *рассмотрите отношение соседних членов ряда*. Очередной член получается просто умножением предыдущего на `-x^2` и делением на `(n+1)(n+2)`. Так куда проще и быстрее.

И вот что получается (я задаю погрешность прямо в программе, и просто считаю таблицу разных значений, и сравниваю с "настоящим" синусом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double series(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = x, term = x;
    int n = 1;
    while(abs(term) > eps)
    {
        term *= -x*x/(n+1)/(n+2);
        n += 2;
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}

const double eps = 1e-8;

int main()
{
    for(double x = 0.0; x < 6.3; x += 0.2)
    {
        cout << setw(8) << x << "  " << setw(10) << series(x,eps)
                             << "  " << setw(10) << sin(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вычислять значение, используя каждый раз на один элемент ряда больше, и каждый раз сравнивая полученное значение с тем, что было получено на предыдущем шаге.

Повторять до тех пор, пока разница не будет меньше, чем заранее заданное ε, которое вводится пользователем перед началом цикла.